# Converting one column of data to three in R

Tags: r

Have three variables labeled "User-ID", "ISBN", and "Book-Rating" in the one column, but prefer three.

Rows: 1,149,903

I read the post about [converting one to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508773/converting-one-column-of-data-into-two-columns-in-r/%22converting%20one%20to%20two%22), but encountered an error on the first line of code.

First Line:

```
 User-ID <- df[seq(from = 1, to =nrow(df), by = 3), 1]
```

Error Message:

```
 Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 3) : 
 'to' must be of length 1
```

I saved the .csv file as a data.frame using:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(BX.Book.Ratings)
```

Below shows screenshot. Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a **reproducible** example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: Try `read.table("BX-Book-Ratings.csv", sep=";")`

Comment: I am going to guess that you are using `read.csv` to read in the data.   Most of the parameters in that function are dummy variables in that they do not change the functionality.  As @Manetheran suggested, use `read.table` instead.

Comment: Probably safer not to use variables with dashes in them, like `User-ID`.

Comment: @beroe thanks will keep that in mind. I downloaded this from a website as test data. link:https://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/. Used the CSV dump link

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
 read.table(text=BX.Book.Ratings$V1,sep=";",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto -- Sadly, I didn't get out of bed until hours later, and SO's time tagging isn't that precise :-(  . I'd assumed (yeah, bad me) from Saporta's comment that agstudy's answer didn't show up until later on.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, SO's time tagging is actually *very* precise--hover over the time values for the specific time :) I'm just provoking you--I doubt either user cares much about it much....

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Thanks for the hover-tip.  I never knew that.  And to agstudy: most certainly it was a weak joke.  I need to use those <sarcasm> tags.

Comment: @agstudy Thank you for getting back. I put in read.table(text=BX.Book.Ratings$V1,sep=";",header=TRUE). I got the following error: 
Error in textConnection(text) : invalid 'text' argument

Comment: @Manetheran I put in your command and got the following result. [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1038576 rows ] I am trying to find the command for viewing the table

Comment: @Manetheran I made a mistake of not putting the file name. Here is the new command: BXBOOKRATINGS <- read.table("BX-Book-Ratings.csv", sep=";"). Viewed the data, but still has 1048576 obs. of 1 variables. My intention involves separating the data into three variables. Thanks again